# EvoPdf - How to fill empty space between table end and footer with empty rows

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, evopdf

HTML -> PDF. How can I render an unknown number of empty rows, from the last row with data until reach footer? [you can see the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCD0e.png). The issue is that sometimes rows in the data part will be single-row, sometimes multi-row. My tries:

1. in razor @for(int i = 0; i < 70; i++) {...} - and try to crop rows that go to next page with "overflow-y:hidden"
2. setting "height:auto" for the last row (without for loop), so it can fit remaining space, and then set background (that will look like alternated rows) for that row
3. https://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/Headers_and_Footers/Header_Footer_Auto_Resize.aspx. In this try alternated lines were part of the footer, so I try to dynamically adjust its height

Comment: The solution, but not ideal: # of rows on 1 pdf page is for example 25, so # of empty lines will be 25 - # of rows with data. If data goes to the 2nd page, then 50 - # of rows with data and so on. Not ideal, because some data will be multi-line, so height will not be equal for all rows. So I put 2 less empty lines like buffer

Comment: also, answer form evoPdf is that I can't achieve this behavior with their library. Guy suggests htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.SinglePage = true, but that solution wasn't good for us.